# html2canvas take screenshot of DIV element?

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, html2canvas

I am trying to make div element screenshot, but combined with draggable jQuery, and have no luck, I can take screenshot of div and save it like png, but if I drag some elements on that div and then save screenshot I get only what is inside that div and draggable elements over that div? Any idea, this mine code so far

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myBtn").click(function () {
        html2canvas($("#chartDiv"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var imgSrc = canvas.toDataURL();
                $("#myDiv").html('').show();
    var url = "ajax.php";
    $.post(url, {contentVar: imgSrc} ,function(data) {
       $("#myDiv").html(data).show();
    });
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  });
  </script>
```

I am using AJAX to save image and present in new element

**AJAX.PHP**

```
$contentVar = $_POST['contentVar'];

$filteredData=substr($_POST['contentVar'], strpos($_POST['contentVar'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('img.png', $unencodedData);

echo "<img src="img.png">";
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div id="chartDiv"><img src="img/assets/logo.png"></div>
<button id="myBtn">Create image</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<img src="img/assets/logo.png" class="draggable" />
<img src="img/assets/logo.png" class="draggable" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not disable the the draggalbe elements before taking the screenshot, then re-enabling them.  This will remove the jquery_ui draggable elements and css.